# TableView to change with UIButton on another viewcontroller

Tags: tableview, uiswitch

I have a custom cell table view showing arrays with 4 different infos, on 4 labels.

On another view controller I have a UISwitch, which if switched off, should lead to one of the labels to not show anything.

I was thinking to create a boolean, but this does not get picked up in the tableview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the label conditionally in cellForRowAtIndexPath and just call reloadData on the tableView when you hit the switch.